# hook_theme default arguments not recognised in template

Tags: 7, hooks

When using hook_theme I create an array of variables with default values:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_theme
 */
function my_module_theme() {

  return array(

    'my_theme' => array(
      'arguments' => array(
        'var1' => 'default value',
      ),
      'template' => 'my-theme',
    ),

  );
}
```

And the template file my-theme.tpl.php:

```
<div><?php print $var1; ?></div>
```

But inside the corresponding template the $var1 variable is only recognised if I explicitly send it with the theme() implementation:

```
print theme('my_theme', array('var1' => 'New var'); // No errors

print theme('my_theme'); // Notice: Undefined variable: var1 in include()
```

My understanding of the default arguments are just that - they should be the default if they are not explicitly defined. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do like

/**
 * Implementation of hook_theme
 */
function my_module_theme() {

return array(

```
'my_theme' => array(
  'variables' => array(
    'var1' => 'default value',
  ),
  'template' => 'my-theme',
),
```

);
}

Instead of arguments use variables.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your variable to take default value then you first need to define that variable in your_theme_preprocess_HOOK() function then only your variable will be available in template file without any php notice.